# Como retornar apenas os resultados que tenham apenas a determinada condição

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

```
 select 
CODIGO_GRUPO
,CODIGO_COTA 
,NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA


from COBRANCAS c

where 2=2
and CODIGO_MOVIMENTO = 270 

and NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA = 1 
and VERSAO = 0
and CODIGO_GRUPO >= 440
```

esse select retonar

```
codigo grupo  | codigo cota | numero assembleia
   
   440              01             01

   440              02             01         

   440              03             01
```

porem na minha tabela eu sei que tenho estes mesmos grupos e cotas com o numero de assembleia nº 2 e eu gostaria de retornar apenas os que estivessem o numero de assembleia  1

Answer (score -2):

Experimente acrescentar a condição abaixo no Where para verificar se existe outra linha para o grupo / cota:

```
and not exists
    (select 1 from COBRANCAS s
     where 
         s.CODIGO_GRUPO = c.CODIGO_GRUPO and
         s.CODIGO_COTA = c.CODIGO_COTA and
         s.NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA <> c.NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA)
```